# Laravel Skip Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: laravel

Trying to save some records to my database,
But It returns errors like:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

But I don't want it to stop my job.
Skip error, don't create record and continue to my job.

How to skip that?

Comment: use try catch. they are usefull where you expect error and handle them as you please like create a report of the faulty entries. another usefull tool is to use database commit/rollback if you have entries dependant on the faulty ones

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    $user->save();
}catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    if($e->getCode() === '23000') {
        // you got the duplicate
    }
    if($e->getCode() === '1452') {
        // Cannot add or update a child row
    }
}
```